# Is it possible to get the column length in a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I don't want what is defined for the table, I want to do something like

`select id, name, LEN(NAME) from foo`

But that doesn't seem to work in MySql.  Is there a function to get the column length?

Comment: I think I found it...LENGTH(). sorry to bother you all.

Comment: Not sure if you need certain rep to remove the question, but you can always answer your own questions.

Comment: I probably could have but someone took the time to answer the question and as far as I can tell it isn't a duplicate so I don't mind giving someone else full credit for answering.  I appreciate it when people take the time to make my life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `LENGTH()` function.

```
select id, name, LENGTH(NAME) from foo
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [LENGTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_length), not LEN(), to count bytes and [CHAR_LENGTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) to count chars.

Answer (score 1):

Use char_length(name)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CHAR_LENGTH function:

```
select id, name, CHAR_LENGTH(NAME) from foo
```

[MySQL Ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length)

Comment: +1 for adding the MySQL Ref, that is what I found about 5 minutes after posting the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want the length of the column *value*?

```
select id, name, length(NAME) from foo
```